# Do you need to be signed into Twitter in iOS to use the Twitter API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

Do you need to be signed into Twitter in iOS to use the Twitter API? I know you can use the iOS accounts library to sign into Twitter and access the API, but if you have a registered Twitter APP ID, is it possible to access the Twitter API without the user of the App being signed into Twitter already?

Comment: I think the whole twitter API now requires user authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter API normally requires both the Twitter application and the user to authenticate.

Now, there is a special [App Only](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) where only the application needs to authenticate. However, in this mode, you can only use a subset of the API.

You can, for instance, retrieve your company's timeline, but you cannot post a new tweet, because there is no user context.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15419005/55137) shows how to use the App Only mode with the [STTwitter library](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter).

You can create Twitter application [here](https://apps.twitter.com/).

Comment: I'm just interested in being able to search with the API, do I need both types of authentication for that? or just the App only version?

Comment: You can perfectly use the App Only mode with the search API `search/tweets.json`. Example with STTwitter here: http://pastebin.com/Kkn2Wgen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no need to be *logged in* one of them for each other but you need an account for both of them, so you need to be *signed in*. ;oP

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You're saying that the App needs to be signed in, but an user of the App doesn't have to be signed in for the app to use the API? or they both have to be signed in?

Comment: I fear we are confusing ourselves, we are speaking about 5 different things : the fact to be *signed in* (or *registered*), the fact to be *logged in* (or *connected*), the Twitter *website*, the Twitter *App* (or *mobile application*, I suppose iPhone's one) and the Twitter *API* (or *Application Programming Interface*). So to develop programs around Twitter *API* nothing is needed but to use it you need to be registered and you will connect to Twitter by then. ;oP